# Ubuntu studio/xubuntu 12.04 instead of Ubuntu 12.04/12.10 for CAD/ arhcitectural workflow. Worth it?

Tags: 12.04, cad, bricscad

I am currently using Ubuntu 12.10. So, as described in the title I am planning to install Ubuntu studio. The programs i use are Blender, Maya 2013, NukeX, Bricscad, Sketchup (with wine) and also i am planning to install revit architecture through VirtualBox. Well, I am using a quad-core CPU and i want to have all the power of my system for rendering/modelling. So, i decided to try a more lightweight desktop than unity.
Also, what made me to decide this, is that when i tried to install Bricscad v12 the program does not work. So, i thought that if i want something more professional for my work i should have only LTS versions of lightweight Ubuntu.

So, my 2 questions are :1) Worth it?
                        2) Can i have global menu(close,minimize,maximize buttons, menu) like ubuntu/unity?

Thanks

Comment: 1-It's really up to you, so try it.//2.No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest installing Kubuntu instead, and then just install whatever free software you want. Ubuntu Studio doesn't come with anything you can't get in Ubuntu/Kubuntu anyway.

I went with Kubuntu because Unity, being based on Compiz, cannot support more than one graphics card. I think KDE is better than Unity anyway. The KDE project has been under active development since 1996 and it's got a much cleaner interface. I can design stuff on the center monitor and have auxiliary information on the side monitors. This is EXTREMELY nice when you are designing something and need to look at photos or read information, because there is almost zero context switch. You can look at supporting information without making the main app "go away." If you're already running your brain at full tilt, every bit helps, and this is a game changer.

Comment: Ubuntu Studio does not use Unity it uses XFCE, and it's faster than KDE.

Answer (score 1):

There's a fix to make Bricscad run on Ubuntu 12.10.

[See here](http://linuxaideddesign.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-fix-bricscads-segfault-on-ubuntu.html)